# SQL SUM() the 3 best values of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like the following :

tablename: user

```
name           points      id_subligue ...
------------------------------------------
user1        100              1
user2        200              1
user3        300              1
user4        400              1
```

when i do this:

```
SELECT user.name,  user.points AS TOTAL
FROM user
WHERE user.id_subligue='1'
ORDER BY user.points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Exit:

```
name        TOTAL
------------------
user4        400
user3        300
user2        200
```

If i do this:

```
SELECT  SUM(user.points) AS TOTAL
FROM user
WHERE user.id_subligue='1'
ORDER BY user.points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Exit:

```
TOTAL
-----
1000
```

I wish the sum of 3 best user by points! not the sum of all user with id_subligue='1'. So TOTAL=900
Any ideas?
What i am doing wrong? o how can i do it?
Thanx!

## Heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      SUM(user.points) AS TOTAL

from       (SELECT user.points 
            FROM user
            WHERE user.id_subligue='1'
            ORDER BY user.points DESC
            LIMIT 3
            ) user
```

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: Sorry again! In table user i have different 'name' in different 'id_subligue' so i would like for each subligue...not just user.id_subligue='1'. I hope it is clear what i want and u can help me. Thanks in advance! For example: id_subligue 1 = 900; id_subligue 2 = xxx ...

Answer (score 2):

If you group your query results by users, you will get sums of points per user.

```
SELECT SUM(user.points) AS TOTAL, user.name
FROM user
WHERE user.id_subligue='1'
GROUP BY user.name
ORDER BY user.points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Hi Aycan! that is not what i want! i need the sum of the three best user points in TOTAL. Its solved by Dudu Markovitz. Thank you!

Comment: @agustincola So I guess you've chosen my answer as correct answer by mistake. You may wish to select Dudu Markovitz's answer, instead of mine.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, it seems i am very new. Thank Aycan!